webrtc lte -> wifi Not connected
I am implementing webrtc real-time voice chat in React Native Android. I built a turn server using coturn. However, if you think that the configuration of coturn is incorrect and you purchase and apply ExpressTURN's turn server, webrtc will only work in the local environment. The only time it worked as LTE on wifi was when I used coturn. Communication takes place over https, but the certificate uses a root certificate and is not issued by an authority. The certificate has not been applied to the turn server.
I can't figure out the cause.
If anyone has figured out the cause and solved this symptom, please help me.

wifi(private) -> wifi(private) = success

lte -> lte = success

wifi(private) -> lte = success

lte -> wifi (private) = failure

wifi(hotspot) -> lte = success

lte -> wifi (hotspot) = failure



async initialize() {
  try {
    await this.initializeData()
    
    this.peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({
      iceServers: [
        // { urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' },
        {
          urls: [
            "turn:??",
            "turn:??",
            "turn:??",
            "turn:??",
            "turn:??",
          ],
          username: '??',
          credential: '??',
        }
      ]
    })

    this.localStream = await mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false })
    this.localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => this.peerConnection.addTrack(track, this.localStream))

    // 피어 이벤트
    this.peerConnection.addEventListener('track', this.onTrackEvent)
    this.peerConnection.addEventListener('icecandidate', this.onIcecandidateEvent)

    this.peerConnection.addEventListener('connectionstatechange', (event) => {
      console.log(`connectionState`, this.peerConnection?.connectionState)
    })
    this.peerConnection.addEventListener('iceconnectionstatechange', (event) => {
      console.log(`iceConnectionState`, this.peerConnection?.iceConnectionState)
    })
    this.peerConnection.addEventListener('signalingstatechange', () => {
      console.log(`signalingState`, this.peerConnection?.signalingState)
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}

onTrackEvent = (event) => {
  try {
    this.remoteStream = event.streams[0]
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}

onIcecandidateEvent = (event) => {
  try {
    if (event.candidate) {
      socketManager.socket?.emit('WebRTC_ICEcandidate', { target: id, candidate: event.candidate })
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}

onIcecandidateEvent = (event) => {
  try {
    if (event.candidate) {
      socketManager.socket?.emit('WebRTC_ICEcandidate', { target: id, candidate: event.candidate })
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}

async startOffer() {
  try {
    const offer = await this.peerConnection?.createOffer()
    await this.peerConnection?.setLocalDescription(offer)

    socket?.emit('WebRTC_startOffer', { target: id, offer: offer })
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}

async answerOffer({ offer }) {
  try {
    await this.peerConnection?.setRemoteDescription(offer)

    const answer = await this.peerConnection?.createAnswer()
    await this.peerConnection?.setLocalDescription(answer)

    socket?.emit('WebRTC_answerOffer', { target: id, answer: answer })
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}

async setRemoteOffer({ answer }) {
  try {
    await this.peerConnection?.setRemoteDescription(answer)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}

async setRemoteIceCandidate({ iceCandidate }) {
  try {
    if (this.peerConnection) {
      this.peerConnection?.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(iceCandidate))
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}



STUN server is required, you can use your own or google one;
As a next step is to check your turn server, if its working well. You can use this link: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/


The issue was resolved by regenerating the offer in onNegotiationNeededEvent during a peer event.
